# Do bitcoin pay accelerators actually work?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I am asking because I have a bitcoin transaction that has been stuck for about a week. I put the one too many zeroes somewhere and the transaction only charges about 23 satoshis per byte. Also, if anyone knows some miners who could help me out, I would send them some extra bitcoin. The transaction is: 0b430ad7be7e1ce39eaaa5e8f92adb764820a8fbb8da89acd96b84f234ad0675

Answer (score 2):

Some transaction accelerators work, [while others are probably scam](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_accelerator) .

You can check out [Bitcointalk.org->Economy->Marketplace->Sevices](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=52.0).
Some members there offer FREE acceleration services, and have access to a variety of pools.
However, be aware if you decide to go for the PAID services, don't fall for the scammy ones.

Answer (score 2):

When a transaction is "Stuck" for more than a day, the easiest solution is just to rebroadcast it. You can use some free transaction accelerators like https://bitaccelerate.com/ . They are actually rebroadcasting your transaction via several nodes. BitAccelerate is currently rebroadcasting via 7 public nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I think so since the miners control Bitcoin transaction so yes, they can pick specific transaction to mine.
it's a good mining pool and they support this feature
https://pool.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/